# Primefaces 6 - commandlink action not fired

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am using primefaces6.0 on Jsf2.0 & mojarra 2.0.9-SNAPSHOT.

I have a commandLink on the actions facet of a panel. This panel is rendered using ui:repeat so as to be dynamic. The panels are grouped inside a Tab.

So the i have dynamic p:tab , and inside each tab, the panels are rendered using ui:repeat.

My problem is the commandLInk action or actionlistener is called only for the first panel of each tab. When i click on other panels of the same tab - the action is not fired.

Any leads ?

Below is my xhtml code.

```
<p:tabView  id="tabViewId"
                value="#{userdashboard.chartGroupsList}" var="cg" onTabShow="reflowChart()">


                <p:tab title="#{cg.groupName}" >

                    <ui:repeat var="c" value="#{cg.charts}" varStatus="status">

                       <ui:fragment rendered="#{c.typeCode ne 'TABLE1'}">
                           <div class="Container#{c.chartSpecificContainerWidth} Responsive#{c.chartSpecificContainerWidth} NoIndent" 
                                id="parentDivId#{c.rowid}" >


                                <p:panel  header="" styleClass="panelChart" 
                                    toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal">

                                    <f:facet name="actions" >
                                        <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default"
                                            action="#{userdashboard.updateUIColumnLayout}" ajax="false">
                                            <h:outputText  value="#{c.id}"/>
                                        </p:commandLink>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:panel>
                        </ui:fragment>

                     </ui:repeat>

                </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: does it acces to the method ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight it does access the method only for the first panel of each tab, but it does not access the method for other panels